# On a multi-user Android device, when Google Backup runs, whose data will get backed up?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, backup, multi-user, google-backup, backup-manager

If it's enabled, Google Backup does two things.

A)  It runs "key/value backups", maybe once every few hours, and it stores the data in the Android Backup Service.

B)  It runs "Android Auto Backups", usually once per night, and it stores the data in your Google Drive.

[(Source.)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup#Choosing)

On a multi-user Android device, when Google Backup runs, whose data will get backed up?

(I could do some testing and find out the answer myself, but it might take me days.  My device is running Android 6.0.0 "Marshmallow", and I'm not sure I've yet figured out how to properly force a full immediate backup using `bmgr` on such an old OS.)

## Edit

`adb shell` then `dumpsys backup` will mention "Backup currently running" if a backup is running.  It can also tell you much more information.

`adb shell` then `logcat | grep -i backup` will watch for backup-related activity and show you the log entries as they happen.

## To read more about multi-user backup

If you'd like to see other threads about multi-user backup, please go [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-user+backup) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-user+titanium-backup).

Comment: The first search [result](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Android+backup+multiple+users&oq=Android+backup+multiple+users&aqs=chrome..69i57.9815j0j7&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) raised in Google forums indicate that only primary user is backed up. Other questions on this search page including this site seem to support

Comment: Even [adb doesn't backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978678/adb-backup-restore-multiple-users-apps) multiple users